# Is the tensor product of Hilbert spaces still Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I learnt that:

$$\bigoplus_{i\in\mathcal I}\mathcal H_i=\mathcal H$$

$\mathcal H$ denotes Hilbert space. Does the following also hold?

$$\bigotimes_{i\in\mathcal I}\mathcal H_i=\mathcal H$$

My guess is no, but I am not sure how to prove this rigorously.

$I$ could be either countable or uncountable.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces

Comment: Your terminology is unusual.  I'd say something like "I learnt that if $\mathcal H = \bigoplus_{i\in\mathcal I}\mathcal H_i$, then $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space".

Comment: In any case, it would help if you defined $\bigotimes_{i\in\mathcal I}\mathcal H_i$ in some way.  Are we just looking at finite linear combinations of simple tensors?